# There's an error with 'end expected near eof ' and I can't find the solution

Tags: lua, multiplayer

This error came with this script, can anyone find the error?

```
function checkPing(thePlayer)
    ping = getPlayerPing(thePlayer)
    if ( ping > 500 ) then
    kickPlayer (thePlayer ,ToohighPing)
    outputChatBox (getPlayerName(thePlayer).."Has been kicked due to High ping",255,255,0)
end
addEventHandler ("OnResourceStart")
```

Comment: We're not your free debugging service.

Comment: maybe move "end" to the end?

Comment: no it's not working, 'end' expected near '<eof>' :(

Comment: 'eof' means end of function. So you need another end at the end of your function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have two `end`s: one to close the `if` statement and one to close `function`. You are probably missing `end` between lines 5 and 6.